# Small capitals if available, normal (large) capitals if not

Tags: xetex, pdftex, small-caps

In French, it is customary to typeset centuries and other numbers in Roman numerals in small capitals if available, or normal (large) capitals if not. If I use `\textsc{vi}` to typeset "6", I risk it being typeset as "vi" if small capitals are not available.

Is there a way to use small capitals if available, and normal (large) capitals otherwise? (Both with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX)

Comment: With XeLaTeX you can use the `\fontspec[Letters=UppercaseSmallCaps]{...}` option if your font has the `c2sc` option which should degrade to the small-caps.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not what you had in mind, but a practical solution is to define a command in your preamble that either chooses uppercase letters or small caps and enable this with your choice of font.

```
\newcommand\mysc[1]{\textsc{#1}}
...
\usepackage{font with no small caps}
\renewcommand\mysc[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```

Since you have to change your preamble anyway to choose a new font, if you keep this redefinition right by the font choice, it should be easy enough to do.

Here is an attempt to automate this. **Warning**: the present code is extremely fragile, but it shows the basic idea.  I am using bera-sans which has no small caps.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\normalfont

\providecommand{\mysc}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\makeatletter
\fontshape\scdefault
\expandafter\ifx\csname\curr@fontshape\endcsname\relax
  \renewcommand{\mysc}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
2000\textsc{ad} vs 2000\mysc{ad}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is that, with NFSS, the macro `\curr@fontshape` will expand to a command name that is defined if the font is provided (in this case `\curr@fontshape -> T1/fvs/m/sc` and the command `\T1/fvs/m/sc -> \relax` is undefined).  I had to do this *before* `\selectfont` was called, otherwise a substitution will be defined (`\<->s*[.9]fvsr8t` in this case) so I use `\fontshape\scdefault` rather than `\scshape` in the test (as the latter calls `\selectfont`).

One could probably also do some text-processing on the command to alter the behaviour even if a substitution is defined but I am not sure how to best do that right now.

**References**

- [source2e.pdf](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf): I could not find anywhere where this was explicitly documented, so I had to look into the source.  See for example, line 294.